# postgres count or sum ignoring dirty stuff

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, sum

I have an index where the information that has to be summed up is in the index. Index looks like this `(key,sumable_attribute)`.

Now if I say:

```
SELECT sum(sumable_attribute) from table where key between 1 and 1000000
```

It would be perfect if we can run along the linked leafs of the b-tree and collect the sumable_attributes.

BUT: MVCC tells us to check the visibility of the data... I don't care if my result isn't 100% correct, as long as it is fast. MyISAM kind of fast...

How do I tell postgres to ignore this?

Comment: If you don't care about the accuracy of data coming out of your database, you should probably take a step away from the keyboard until you do

Comment: I also don't see what MVCC has to do with this

Comment: What if everybodys problem today? Image you have a bank and are interested how much cash is available to make a quick decision you can't tell me that you care about someone gettint 10 bucks from an atm. Ready dirty data is very common in databases so please don't tell me that this is wrong. In the needed context it doesn't matter if the result is 0,01 % of.

Comment: @Adam MVCC forces a visit to table, to check if the data is visible. Without the visit to the table the information can directly be taken from the leafs of the index. No random IO on the disk. Makes things soooo much faster. For this use case a very good tradeoff

Comment: Try rephrasing the question in terms of what you actually want. For example, "I want to run this query, but it's too slow. Here's my index. What can I do?"

Comment: This is not directly a consequence of MVCC, but a consequence of the fact that index blocks in Postgres do not carry MVCC information. That's why the check in the table is necessary. Oracle and others - which implement MVCC as well - do have the visibility information in the index and thus could satisfy the query completely from the index. Currently there are plans to implement this for Postgres as well, but this is future talk (it will not happen for 9.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL currently implements [two distinct isolation levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html): "Read Committed" and "Serializable". You can ask for a dirty read with `READ UNCOMMITTED`, but you'll get "Read Committed" isolation level instead.

Since `READ COMMITTED` is the default, you're probably using the fastest isolation level PostgreSQL offers.

But posting the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE query_name_or_sql_statement` might give us some ideas.

Comment: Okay this was still more theoretical because I am still deciding which database-system to use. But this is a mayor drawback. No workaorund possible? That means I have to use cubes to keep performance acceptable, that's just what I didn't want to do... :-(

Comment: The only workaround I can think of off the top of my head is to create a table for the sum, and write a trigger to keep it up to date. (And, maybe, write another procedure that runs 'n' times a day to make sure the stored sum and the calculated sum are in sync.)  If I were you, I'd build, load, and test.  Everybody offers a free version of their DBMS nowadays. And I've been pleasantly surprised more than once by actual performance.

Comment: Another approach in PostgreSQL might be to use partial indexes. Don't know whether that applies in your case, though.

Comment: Another idea: putting the index in a tablespace on a solid-state disk. Or maybe putting the table *and* the index on SSD.